# Google Play private Channel "Restrict Distribution" is not visible

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to publish app through Google Play Private Channel.What step i followed is as below

```
     1. Sign-In with name@xyzcomp.com in Gmail mail App (i am not admin of our domain   www.xyzcomp.com)
     2. Go to Google Play Developer Console 
     3. Paid $25 successfully.
     4. Upload testAPK (not published)
     5. Verify domain (xyzcomp.com)
     6. click on Pricing & Distribution
```

But i am not able see **Restrict Distribution** . [image]
When i go through this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en) , i found that i missed one step that is , but as told i am not admin of domain so i am not able to see these thing through my login.[image]

So, how will I rectify these mistakes? I have one more question I need to contact with domain admin or I can do by myself. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why my question voted down? What is wrong with it. please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with this, but it seems you have to be the administrator of a Google Apps account to restrict distribution on a Google Play private channel. You will have to ask your administrator to enable the feature for you.

Comment: Your administrator, it seems, has only enabled the view private apps on the play store but not put private apps on the play store.